# What is better way to create tables in SQL according to database normalization?

Tags: sql, database-normalization

I have this table **discount_user_product** structure

```
discount_id | user_id | product_id 
------------+---------+------------
          1 |       1 |          1
          1 |       1 |          2
          1 |       2 |          3
```

My tables

**Users**

```
       id |    name | 
----------+---------+-
        1 |   Bobby |         
        2 |     Max |         
        3 |     Joj |
```

**Discounts**

```
       id | discount | expired_at
----------+----------+------------
        1 |      100 |         
        2 |       50 |         
        3 |       30 |
```

**Products**

```
       id | user_id | title 
----------+---------+------------
        1 |       1 | Milk
        2 |       1 | Chees
        3 |       2 | Jeam
```

I would like to use a better tables structure and decompose **discount_user_product** to this structure:

**discount_user**

```
  discount_id | user_id | 
  ------------+---------+-
            1 |       1 |          
            1 |       2 |
```

**user_product**

```
  user_id | product_id | 
  --------+------------+-
        1 |          1 |          
        1 |          2 |          
        2 |          3 |
```

Is this will be the right way to make better performance and compliance with the rules of normalizations?

Comment: What's the purpose of `discount_user_product`? If it grants a discount level to a particular user on a particular product, it doesn't need to be normalised any further.

Comment: why does a produt belong to a user?

Comment: the 3-way intersection expresses that a user gets a certain discount on a particular product. the second way doesn't match up the discounts to products. so seems like it's not the same thing.

Comment: Getting rid of the `discount_user_product` table infers that you want to, instead, blindly grant a user the same discount on every available product.  You lose the ability to selectively grant product discounts.  Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: @NathanHughes  I have updated my user_product table

Comment: ? you still have the same issue. the 2 structures don't represent the same relationships. the 1st way is already normalized btw. there's nothing inherently wrong with it.

Comment: @NathanHughes what do you mean specifically?

Comment: I think Nathan means that the 2nd way means that the discount no longer applies to a specific product. Instead the user gets the same discount on all products. The data means something different in that scenario. So what the correct answer is depends on what your business rules are. Either approach is correctly normalised, but whether it's a correct implementation of the requirements is not something we can tell you.

Comment: @ADyson: yes. At any rate a performance optimization shouldn’t change the essential relationships.

Comment: @NathanHughes absolutely, although I would point out that normalisation it not primarily a tool for performance optimisation. Naturally a properly normalised database is more likely to lead to more performant queries than queries which have to work round poor data structures, but performance involves more factors than this, and one does not directly lead to the other.

Comment: @ADyson: yes, normalization and performance can be at odds with each other. adding indexes is a common performance enhancement, normalization is good for making sure data is consistent. normalization can result in smaller rows with less room taken up by nulls, which lets the database fit more rows in memory and i assume that's what the OP was trying for here.

Comment: Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite a textbook with a bespoke tutorial & do your (home)work & you have shown no research or other effort. Dumps of requirements are not on-topic questions. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Show the steps of your work following your reference with justification & explain re the first place you are stuck. PS Normalization to higher NFs replaces a table by smaller projections of it that join back to it. You don't say enough for us to normalize.